# Potential Energy of 'Triple Spring Mass System'

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, spring, differential-equations

Given the following system, I am trying to find the potential energy and equations of motion.

$\hspace{70mm}$[image]

What I got is
$$\Pi = \frac{1}{2}(c_1(\varphi_2r_2-\varphi_1r_1)^2 + c_2(\varphi_2r_2-\varphi_1r_1)^2+ c_3(\varphi_3r_3-\varphi_2r_2)^2)$$

However, I am currently wondering if we can set up the spring energies as done above, or if we have to take into account whether they'll be pushed or pulled for the considered direction of movement.
I just set it up as
$$c(\varphi_ir_i-\varphi_{i-1}r_{i-1})^2$$ but can this be done in general?

A more correct approach would look like (assuming $J_3$ is moved clockwise)
$$\Pi = \frac{1}{2} (c_1(\varphi_1r_1-\varphi_2r_2)^2 + c_2(\varphi_2r_2-\varphi_1r_1)^2+ c_3(\varphi_2r_2-\varphi_3r_3)^2)$$ however, these two approaches yield the same symmetric matrix $$\mathbf{C} := 
\begin{pmatrix} c_{11} &c_{12} & c_{13}\\ 
c_{21} & c_{22}& c_{23}\\
 c_{31}& c_{32} &c_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$ after fully modelling the system using the Lagrange equations

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial \dot\varphi_i}\right)+\frac{\partial \Pi}{\partial \varphi_i} = 0 \hspace{10mm} \text{for $i = 1,2,3$}$$

Note that the system is modelled as $$\mathbf{J\ddot\varphi+C\varphi = 0}$$ and that the coefficients of $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ can be taken from the evaluated Lagrange expressions.

My question is, if we can model the springs like I did for all systems, or if we have to take push and pull actions into account in general. Because of the symmetry of $\mathbf{C}$ this might not be needed, but I'm not sure.

For both approaches above I got
$$\mathbf{C} = \begin{pmatrix}
r_1^2(c_1+c_2) & -r_1r_2(c_1+c_2) & 0\\
-r_1r_2(c_1+c_2) & r_2^2(c_1+c_2+c_3) & -r_2r_3c_3\\
0& -r_2r_3c_3  &r_3^2c_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take $\frac{1}{2}$ *elastic constant* $\times \Delta length^2$, thus you did it right except for the spring with elastic constant $c_3$, whose potential is

$\frac{1}{2}c_3 (r_3 \phi_3+ r_2 \phi_2)^2$

no matter if compression or traction, since you square it.

Comment: Thanks, I see the mistake for spring $c_3$. So in general the signs dont matter as long as it fits the configuration?

Comment: exactly, since you square it. Anyway $\Delta \ell$ is usually taken to be positive for traction, when the length of the spring increases

Comment: Thus, in the stiffness matrix, elements (2,3) and (3,2) should be positive.

Comment: yep! Simulating this system now with a correct stiffness matrix and some given values gives the second eigenfrequency to be zero. How can I interpret this?

Comment: I guess that the lower eigen-frequency is zero, while you got other two real positive frequencies. The zero eigen-frequency is associated to a free degree of freedom, associated with zero stiffness. This motion corresponds to the rotation of the pulleys with no spring deformation, i.e. $\phi_3 =- \phi_2 r_2/r_3$, $\phi_1 = \phi_2 r_2/r_1$, for every value of $\phi_2$

Comment: You can do it for every value of $\phi_2$ and this corresponds to the definition of an eigenvector, that is defined up to a multiplicative constant. I think there is no much to say about the original question, so please accept the answer. I'll be pleased to help you if you raise other questions, but let each question be focused on a confined topic. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks, sure! I accepted it.